# Using partial package path in Java

Tags: java, organization, java-package

I have some classes like

- `a.b.c.v1.Something`
- `a.b.c.v2.Something`
- `a.b.c.v3.Something`

There is a place where all of them are visible. Is it possible to arrange that I could refer to them like `vX.Something` instead of the lengthy `a.b.c.vX.Something` form?